# Pandas DataFrame, columns within a column

Tags: python, pandas

Here below is the CSV file that I'm working with:

[image: table]

I'm trying to get my hands on the `enj coin: (United States)` column. Nonetheless when I try printing all of the columns of the DataFrame it doesn't appear to be treated as a column

Code:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("/multiTimeline.csv")
print(df.columns)
```

I get the following output:

```
Index(['Category: All categories'], dtype='object')
```

I've tried accessing the column with `df['Category: All categories']['enj coin: (United States)']` but sadly it doesn't work.

**Question:**
Could someone possibly explain to me how I could possibly transform this DataFrame (which has only one column `Category: All categories`) into a DataFrame which has two columns `Time` and `enj coin: (United States)`?

Thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using the parameter `skiprows=2` when reading in the CSV. I.e.

```py
df = pd.read_csv("/multiTimeline.csv", skiprows=2)
```

Answer (score 1):

The csv looks good.

Ignore the complex header at the top.

```
pd.read_csv(csvdata, header=[1])
```

The entire header can be taken in as well, although it is not delimited as the data is.

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas.compat import StringIO
print(pd.__version__)

csvdata = StringIO("""Category: All categories

Time,enj coin: (United States)
2019-04-10T19,7
2019-04-10T20,20""")

df = pd.read_csv(csvdata, header=[0,1])
print(df)
```

```
0.24.2
              Category: All categories
                                  Time
2019-04-10T19                        7
2019-04-10T20                       20
```

Comment: Interesting that `read_csv()` skips empty rows be default. Thus `header=[0,1]` and not `header=[0,2]`?